# jquery fileuploader - disable upload when pasted - 'fileuploadpaste' - How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

When even I paste any image(on a text input box for example), it is getting uploaded by jquery file uploader.
So, how to stop this?

From the options page(https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options), the event that is triggered after paste is 'fileuploadpaste'.

Normal jquery event fired after text paste is 'textInput'.

So, how to disable this upload ?

Comment: Looks like you need to change the `pasteZone` option according to that link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can simply disable that like this:

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
    pasteZone: null   //make it $(document) or specific container for enabling it
})
```

Comment: I discover this with a very rare bug in my code, thanks!